# Adding same datastore to two Esxi 4.1 servers

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have installed Winodws 7 on it Vmware workstation 7 into it I have created two Esxi 4.1 virtual machines and a 2003 64 bit machine for vCenter.
I have 500 GB HDD on which all these components are installed.
Now I want to practice for VCP exam and want to know how to add my local logical drive on that physical disk as a common datastore for these two ESXi 4.1 VMs?
One option may be that creating a 2003 VM installing NFS on it and presenting it to these ESX VMs.

Is there any option else?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Openfiler to present iSCSI storage to your ESXi hosts. They have a [VMware Virtual Appliance](http://www.openfiler.com/community/download/) that would get you up and running pretty quickly.

Comment: +1, this is probably the best way, Tushar probably needs to work with block storage for at least part of his training and OpenFiler can do NFS too, there's no FC option in this kind of setup. Good luck too Tushar, VCP's not too tough but I'm doing VCAP right now and it's...challenging :)